# Attach terminal and launch docker compose?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

When i run `docker-compose up -d` with following ***docker-compose.yml*** file container is launched and terminates. What is the way to launch using ***docker-compose.yml*** an ubuntu shell which does not exit. (*I understand this is because terminal is not connected to ubuntu so it quits*). Or is there any way to "start a stopped container with terminal attached", so that it wont quit ?

```
ubuntu_x64_v1610:
    image: ubuntu:16.10
    container_name: Ubuntu-x64-v1610
    ports: 
       - 80:80
    environment:
       UBUNTU_VERSION: "x64, v16.10, Shell"
    volumes:
       - /fldr:/root/fldr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `tail -f /dev/null`, or `sleep infinity` if the container's OS supports it by adding following line to docker-compose file

`command: /bin/bash -c "sleep infinity"`